# Block Call Using CallKit

Tags: call, blocking, callkit, identification, callblocking

How i add Contact in Directory, i had add contact in CallDirectoryHander Class it's working fine, but when i want to add phone number dynamic from view Controller Page, then not block call .

I had try  following code to Add contact in directory in view Controller

```
        let cnctNumber  =  phoneNumber.text
        let contentIs = CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext()

        //self.addBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: contentIs )
        numberContact = countryCode + self.phoneNumber.text!
        let numberFromString = Int64(numberContact)

        let phoneNumber : CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber = CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber(numberFromString!)

        contentIs.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)

        contentIs.completeRequest()

        reloadDirectory()//To reload Directory
```

Comment: Were u able to add new contact in CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext?